# Como postar um registro de detalhes em um FDQuery com o registro pai no modo de inserção?

Tags: delphi, firedac

Estou usando dois `FDQuery` com relacionamento mestre-detalhe e encontrei um problema: usando a propriedade `CachedUpdates` e relacionando ambos `FDQuery` à um `FDSchemaAdapter`. Se chamar "*Inserir / Append*" no `Mestre` e depois (com o registro `Mestre` em `dsinsert`) é chamado um "Insert" e em seguida um "Post" no registro detalhe, o seguinte erro ocorre:

> [FireDAC] [DatS] -16. Can not process - no parent row. Constraint
>   [ForeignKeyConstraint].

Eu sei que isso ocorre porque na ordem de "Post", o registro-filho está sendo inserido sem um registro-pai ter sido postado ainda, mas, no banco de dados a chave estrangeira é "Deferred".

Então, como faço para que o `FireDac` ignore apenas essa restrição sem desativar a propriedade `DetailCascade` e manter a funcionalidade de "exclusão / atualização" em cascata em cache?

Já tentei usar `FDSchemaAdapter.DatSManager.EnforceConstraints`, mas o resultado é semelhante a desabilitar a propriedade `DetailCascade` da `FDquery`.

**Nota:** estou usando Delphi XE5.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, no Delphi XE5, usando o recurso de `DetailCascade` não é possível por meio das propriedades nativas do componente. Somente a partir da versão Berlin ou superior desmarcando a propriedade [DetailServerCascade](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.DetailServerCascade). 
A alternativa nada agradável num cenário de muitos níveis é não usar `DetailCascade` e fazer as operações manualmente.